# How do I create a new column based on matching values in two different dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have two dataframes:

df1 (a row for every event that happens in the game)

| Date | Game | Event Type | Player | Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 02/28/10 | USA vs Canada | Faceoff | Sidney Crosby | 20:00 |
| 02/28/10 | USA vs Canada | Pass | Drew Doughty | 19:59 |
| 02/28/10 | USA vs Canada | Pass | Scott Niedermayer | 19:42 |
| 02/28/10 | USA vs Canada | Shot | Sidney Crosby | 18:57 |
| 02/28/10 | USA vs Canada | Takeaway | Dany Heatley | 18:49 |
| 02/28/10 | USA vs Canada | Shot | Dany Heatley | 18:02 |
| 02/28/10 | USA vs Canada | Shot | Sidney Crosby | 17:37 |

df2

| Player |
| --- |
| Sidney Crosby |
| Dany Heatley |
| Scott Niedermayer |
| Drew Doughty |

How do I create a new column in df2 that matches the Player column in each dataframe and counts each row where the Event Type in df1 is "Shot"?

This is the output I would look for in this example:

| Player | Shots |
| --- | --- |
| Sidney Crosby | 2 |
| Dany Heatley | 1 |
| Scott Niedermayer | 0 |
| Drew Doughty | 0 |

I'm new to Python, so I apologize if there's an easy answer that I'm missing. Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried this far? A code example is always good. Ask others to help to find a bug in your code, not writing code for yoyu

Comment: @ex4 My apologies! I'm new to the community. I did try some various things that didn't get what I wanted. I'll be sure to post what code I've tried whenever my next question comes about!

Comment: No worries and welcome to Stack Overflow. There is system in SO where more experienced users review first posts of new users and help them follow guidelines. Your question came up when I was reviewing them. That why the comment. Great to have new active users here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the `df1` for `shot`, then do a value count:

```
shots = df1.loc[df1['Event Type']=='shot', 'Player'].value_counts()

df2['shots'] = df2['Player'].map(shots)
# or using reindex with `fill_value` option
# shots.reindex(df2['Player'], fill_value=0).values
```

---

**Bonus:** Use `crosstab` and `merge` to get all statistics at once:

```
df2.merge(pd.crosstab(df1['Player'], df1['Event Type']),
          on='Player', how='left')
```